# ProgressDialog shows before 2nd TabBar fragment is opened

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs

I have 3 tabs in my main activity. In the 2nd tab I have a fragment that has a list and I am using Retrofit to get data from my server and display it in the list.

In my 2nd fragment I have:

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recents, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    getBooks();

}

private void getBooks(){

    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Fetching Data", "Please wait...", false, false);

   /* Retrofit code: */

    //Creating a rest adapter
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL)
            .build();

    //Creating an object of our api interface
    MyAPI api = adapter.create(MyAPI.class);

    //Defining the method
            api.getBooks(new Callback<List<MyPojo>>() {
                @Override
                public void success(List<MyPojo> list, Response response) {
                    //Dismissing the loading progressbar
                    loading.dismiss();

                    //Storing the data in our list
                    pojos = list;
                    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), pojos);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    //you can handle the errors here
                    loading.dismiss();

                    Log.v("Error: ", "" + error);
                }
            });
}
```

my problem is that the progress dialog is shown as soon as the app is launched in the 1st tab..I want it to fetch the data only when the 2nd tab is opened.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [developer guide for fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), a fragment's lifecycle (see Figure 2 in the link) is only active (i.e. displayed and the user can interact with it) between the `onResume()` and `onPause()` android callbacks.

If you want something to only occur when the fragment is displayed, place the code for showing it in the `onResume()` callback.  You can pre-fetch or do other setup in other callbacks if you like.

Comment: I tried to show the ProgressDialog in onResume() but it still shows in the 1st tab.

Comment: is the fragment `onResume()` method being run even when the second tab isn't shown?  Maybe put a DEBUG log statement in the method or a breakpoint and see if it is executing even when the fragment isn't visible.  I suppose I wouldn't expect it to be, since it's not visible, until the 2nd tab is shown.  If that is the case, then wrap the code to show the fragment in a conditional that checks which tab is visible.

Comment: I tried to add a debug log in onResume it did execute when the 1st tab was opened.. still the same problem ..and the log appeared after a while not sure why ?

Comment: Post your code in the question.  If the obvious answer doesn't work, seeing the code helps to short-circuit endless discussion.

Comment: I have added the code in the question please check it out .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put the network code in your second `Fragment`'s `onResume()`

```
@Override
  public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Fetching Data", "Please wait...", false, false);

     (and the rest is the Retrofit code)

  }
```

Comment: I tried but I still get the progress dialog as soon as my app is launched